# Ubuntu Server Boot Loop

Tags: boot, server

After a fresh installation on a HP DL380 G9, during OS/kernel bootstrap, there are some errors on init and they keep looping searching for HP virtual keyboard devices and the result is that the system doesn't boot at all. There where no changes made to the system(BIOS).

Here is the error information:

```
[    7.537746] rtc_cmos 00:08: setting system clock to 2014-09-16 02:28:06 UTC (1410834486)    
[    7.542414] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    7.544317] EDD information not available.
[    7.547741] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1336K (ffffffff81d20000 - ffffffff81e6e000)
[    7.585955] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k
[    7.616328] Freeing unused kernel memory: 796K (ffff880001739000 - ffff880001800000)
[    7.656059] Freeing unused kernel memory: 688K (ffff880001b54000 - ffff880001c00000)
Mount failed for selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux:  No such file or directory
[    7.706294] random: init urandom read with 2 bits of entropy available
[    7.721931] init: Error while reading from descriptor: Bad file descriptor
[    7.724190] init: Error while reading from descriptor: Bad file descriptor
[    7.726587] init: plymouth-ready (startup) main process (210) terminated with status 127
[    7.729220] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (211) terminated with status 1
[    7.729273] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    7.733669] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    7.735830] init: hwclock main process (214) terminated with status 127
[    7.746411] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (219) terminated with status 1
[    7.748868] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    7.754686] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (224) terminated with status 1
[    7.757309] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    7.765746] init: plymouth main process (225) terminated with status 71
[    7.768177] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (229) terminated with status 1
[    7.770624] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    7.776260] init: mountall main process (228) terminated with status 127
[    7.865648] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    7.867768] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    7.870208] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    7.871641] hub 1-1:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    7.985145] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    8.117523] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    8.119627] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    8.122304] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    8.123775] hub 2-1:1.0: 8 ports detected
[    8.193053] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 1795.672 MHz
[    8.236993] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    8.386787] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=7029
[    8.388922] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    8.391116] usb 3-1: Product: Virtual Keyboard
[    8.392530] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: HP
[    8.508907] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
[    8.652100] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=2127
[    8.654697] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    8.657037] usb 3-2: Product: iLO Virtual USB Key
[    8.658669] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: HP
[    8.736997] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    8.830241] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=2027
[    8.832407] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    8.834649] usb 2-1.1: Product: iLO Virtual USB CD/DVD ROM
[    8.836606] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: HP
[    8.908913] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    9.001118] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2660
[    9.003259] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    9.006167] hub 2-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[    9.007532] hub 2-1.3:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    9.192855] Switched to clocksource tsc
[   17.061193] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   19.283993] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
[   19.433672] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=7029
[   19.435779] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   19.437972] usb 3-1: Product: Virtual Keyboard
[   19.439340] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: HP
[   29.207502] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   31.430467] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
[   31.580206] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=7029
[   31.582357] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   31.584534] usb 3-1: Product: Virtual Keyboard
[   31.586000] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: HP++
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus: Please see my additional [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/708783/revisions) making your edit even better!  **;-)** Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thanks @Fabby :) Just wondering how much you are allowed to edit. Like you can submit edits for anything, but what is the furthest you can go with edits?

Comment: Thanks for editing but please use PMs for your chat. This wont get my issue solved. Thanks

Comment: @Chris: I beg to differ: now it's a clear question that *can* be answered. Before bot our edits, it was unclear.  Now: what happens if you boot from a LiveDVD and choose "Try Ubuntu"?  Does that boot?  Which version/flavour of Ubuntu are you trying to boot?

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus: very far.  ping me in chat and we'll continue our discussion there.

Comment: Hi, it is Ubuntu 14.04 Server. I think its an issue with the ILO drivers. I have 8 ubuntu server where 4 are working and 4 are not working. I started to gather the differences. The only differenz I found is that 4 servers were installed with a working internet connection and the others which are not working without. I have currently no possibility to connect them to the internet. Do you think that this could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was an issue with the root device. When booting up it gave up waiting for root partition. Changing the root delay didnt solve it. Erasing all partitions (Reformatting didnt help in my situation) solved the issue.